# How to import data from several txt files

Tags: excel, vba, multi-select

I am still fairly new to vba and have a question regarding data import. I have the following code (below) to import and transpose data from a textfile, however it would be nice to be able to highlight fx five files and then importing them. I guess I need multiselect but how do I get the script to run through all selected files?

Hope you can help med.

Best Regards

Lonnie

```
FILOPEN = Application.GetOpenFilename("Files (*.txt; *.jpg; *.bmp;   

*.tif),*.chr; *_chr.txt; *chr.txt; *.tif", _
 , "Select Picture to Import")
 On Error GoTo LastLine

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FILOPEN, _
    Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'name of file that is imported from
Dim z As String

z = ActiveWorkbook.Name   
Windows(Left(z, Len(z))).Activate

'Copy Data
Range("c1").Select

    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy


Windows(Left(f, Len(f))).Activate 'name of file that is imported into (original sheet)

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `MultiSelect:=True` to your Application.GetOpenFilename method to select multiple files:

```
FILOPEN = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
FileFilter:="Files (*.txt; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif), *.chr; *_chr.txt; *chr.txt; *.tif", _
Title:="Select Picture to Import", _
MultiSelect:=True)
```

Then iterate through the array of results:

```
If IsArray(FILOPEN) Then
    For I = LBound(FILOPEN) To UBound(FILOPEN)
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FILOPEN(I) ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    Next I
End If
```

Comment: Cool, that worked, wrapped it around my entire script and everything is imported and processed :) THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The script below will import all text files for you.  Of course, you can select multiple files, like Taosique demonstrated.  If you want to import all files, run the code below.

```
Sub Import_All_Text_Files_2007()

    Dim nxt_row As Long

     'Change Path
    Const strPath As String = "enter_your_path_here\"
    Dim strExtension As String

     'Stop Screen Flickering
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ChDir strPath

     'Change extension
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")

    Do While strExtension <> ""

         'Adds File Name as title on next row
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strExtension

         'Sets Row Number for Data to Begin
        nxt_row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

         'Below is from a recorded macro importing a text file
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & strPath & strExtension, Destination:=Range("$A$" & nxt_row))
            .Name = strExtension
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
             'Delimiter Settings:
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "="

            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        strExtension = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```